# Assign IP address for container instance on Azure

Tags: azure, containers

I have an image in my container registry and a vnet, example: 10.116.0.0/16 with subnet is 10.116.43.0/24

How can I assign a specific IP address for my container instance in that subnet, example: 10.116.43.100 ?

Comment: thank you very much for you answer. I think I will find another way to solve my problem.

Comment: Which way do you find?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find any solution. So to solve my problem, I have to run container instance first, then I can get its IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not think you can assign a special private IP in the subnet to the container instance manually. Azure will choose the IP for the instance, and there is also no way to set the IP.